# Aligning search input in navbar with materialize

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm trying to build a materialize navbar with some icons and a search bar all aligned. I'm close, but my input box when I click to search is positioned too high. I actually wanted to be able to allow a user to click the search icon and the bar stretch over the whole navbar. But I can't fix the position first.

I wrote a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hz4vkrwb/) to illustrate my problem. You may need to stretch the result panel depending on your screen size. What do I need to change? Here is the HTML

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<nav class="nav-border">
  <div class="nav-wrapper container">
    <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
    <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-menu" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
    <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li>
        <form>
          <div class="input-field">
            <input id="search" type="search" required>
            <label class="label-icon" for="search"><i class="material-icons ">search</i>
            </label>
            <i class="material-icons">close</i>
          </div>
        </form>
      </li>
      <li><a href="collapsible.html"><i class="material-icons">power_settings_new</i></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-menu">
      <li><a href="collapsible.html"><i class="material-icons">power_settings_new</i></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use columns to position the logo, search bar, and right link inside the navbar then change the position property of your search components to `fixed` when the search is active.

This should get you started.

**Working Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
});
```

```css
.nav-wrapper .input-field input[type=search] {
  height: 64px;
}
.nav-wrapper input[type="search"]:focus {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.input-field label {
  max-height: 64px;
}
.nav-wrapper input[type="search"]:focus ~ .label-icon.active {
  position: fixed;
  left: 10px;
}
.nav-wrapper input[type="search"]:focus ~ .closed {
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<nav class="nav-border">
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s2">
          <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
          <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-menu" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
        </div>

        <div class="col s8 hide-on-med-and-down">
          <form>
            <div class="input-field">
              <input id="search" type="search" required>
              <label class="label-icon" for="search"><i class="material-icons">search</i>
              </label>
              <i class="material-icons closed">close</i>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>

        <div class="col s2 hide-on-med-and-down">
          <ul class="right">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="material-icons">power_settings_new</i></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-menu">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="material-icons">power_settings_new</i></a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```